# Reactive form: Set value for another control in HTML

Tags: angular

This is my control

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Role Name" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="rolename" [matAutocomplete]="rolename" >
            <mat-autocomplete #rolename="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of roleAllList" [value]="option.roleName" [attr.roleId]="option.roleId" [attr.roleDesc]="option.roleDescription" (onSelectionChange)="populateRoleDesc(option.roleDescription)">
                {{option.roleName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

In this function populateRoleDesc, I`m receiving the value of roleDescription and setting to another control, rather than using a function for is it possible to set it in HTML itself, I`m using reactive form

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          clientid: ['', Validators.required],
          role: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Kindly let me know if there is a way.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: No issues, I can do by function also, but if it is done via HTML, there won`t be an extra function

Comment: From which control to control you want copy the value ?